# How to access array insider an array for PANDAS python

Tags: python, pandas

For the following array; 
[[[11, 22, 33]]],[[[32, 12, 3]]], I wanted to extract the 1st row and it should output 11,22,33. However, using the following code, I got [[11, 22, 33]].  How can I remove the double bracket?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   [[[11, 22, 33]]], 
                   [[[32, 12, 3]]]
                   ], index=[1, 2], columns=['ColA'])

df[df.index == 1].ColA.item()
```

Expected output should be in the form of **11,22,33**; without the bracket

Comment: 1. That is a horrible structure to be storing in pandas, can you perhaps flatten it instead? 2. That is a *list* not an array. 3. Did you try indexing the list? `df[df.index == 1].ColA.item()[0]` and 4. "11,22,33; without the bracket" makes no sense, it's a list. iterate through it and print values 1 by 1 if that's what you want, or join and make a string.

Comment: Hai Paritosh, thanks for the quick response. Yes, its horrible but that is how the function local_binary_pattern by scikit-image produced. Nevertheless, your alternative still have one pair of bracket left

Comment: You can remove the 3rd dimension in your data before creating the dataframe with `[l[0][0] for l in list_]` with `list_` your 3d list.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick response. Can you provide some example as I cannot digest how exactly to implement your idea

Answer (score 2):

Use `.astype(str)` and `str.replace` with the regex *or* operator (`|`). Then we use `iat` to get the first value:

```
df['ColA'].astype(str).str.replace('\[|\]', '').iat[0]
```

**Output**

```
'11, 22, 33'
```

*Notice*: that the type of your value changed from `list` to `string`

---

Or using native python functions `str` and `replace`:

```
str(df['ColA'].iat[0]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
```

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks for the idea. really appreciate it

Comment: I misunderstood your question, you only want to get the first value without the brackets. See edit for correct output @polosepian